# DrillDown to Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pivot, drilldown

I want to know whether or not it's possible to achieve the following:
On a double click on the pivot table's value items, a data drill down table in a new sheet is created. I am now looking for a way to bypass the double click (via an event handler) and take the data and populate it to an array.

I am going to use the array then to do something else but I haven't been able to figure out an efficient way to use the drill down function non-traditionally.

Edit:
I know the following way: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/778468-modify-pivottable-double-click-behavior.html#post3811859

I am looking for a more ressource efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Work backwards using the f1 help on the pivot table objects to determine this.  But i am not sure it is possible looking at it

Comment: I've tried a bunch of things and read a lot I can't get it to work with the exception of actually having the sheet open and then populating the array before deleting the sheet again.